# Excel Finding average speed

Tags: excel

I have got 1500 rows of travels. In column A I have got total time on travel, in column B total km driven. In column C I did calculation on the average speed of specific travel. Whats the best way to calculate the average speed of all travels? The lengths are from 0 to 20 kms approx, time always shorter than one hour.
First I eliminated all travels shorter than 2 km then
I managed to do a frequency table and have written frequencies of speeds in 0-5,5-10,... km/h. Now I can do a histogram, but should I eliminate more data or how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another cell enter:

```
=SUM(B:B)/SUM(A:A)
```

A common error would be to try to average the values in column **C**.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your data. if it is statistics, don't throw data away, use them.

you have column A for travel time, and column B for travle distance. using this two column you can find the total average speed like what Gary's student suggest i.e. `SUM(B:B)/SUM(A:A)`.

you also have column C the average speed for each travel, you can use this two counter check. simply do `SUMPRODUCT(A:A,C:C)`, you should find the result equals to `SUM(B:B)`. if the results match, then i'll say "ok i'm satisfied with my calculation".